# Team Foundation Server - Yellow Exclamation Points

Tags: tfs

I am working on a project using Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server. I had a folder of various javascript files, and the app ran fine. Then one day all the files had yellow exclamation points, and were no longer in my local directory. I DID NOT DELETE THESE FILES. I don't know what happened, but how do I get these files back? I tried Get Latest Version, which worked successfully for all other files, but did not get new versions of the missing files. How can I get these files back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of "Get Latest", do "Get Specific Version..." (it might be under a sub-menu depending on your client) and tick the two boxes at the bottom:

[image: Get]

This will force download all the files again. Server Workspaces are funny when local things happen and the server is not informed. If you can convert to a local workspace, life gets better and you get a more SVN and less VSS experience.

Comment: And of course it worked perfectly. Thanks! Now I've just got to get rid of those file-deleting hamsters....